# Git - How to get a list of all commits on the remote server

Tags: git, github, git-rev-list

I want to poll github every few minutes for the last 10 commits (commit hash and source branch).

Currently I'm doing

`git -C /path/to/local/repo rev-list --remotes`

and then for each hash trying to get the branch name:

`git -C /path/to/local/repo branch -r --contains #commit-hash#`

and then split by "/" and taking the last component.

but it doesn't always seem to pick up **all** the latest commits.

Is there a better and easier way to do this?

Comment: Use webhooks and only process the new push commits

Comment: Don't just "split by / and take last component" either: what if the branch is named `hello/my/good/friend`?

Answer (score 0):

`rev-list` will not work, because it only looks at your local repository. Don't confuse `--remotes` with asking the remote. `--remotes` just means that the remote tracking branches in your local repository are listed. If you want to have the latest commits on the remote in there, you need to do a `fetch` first.